# Superclass method with subclass data

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Good morning.
Im learning some concepts about inheritance and consoles manipulation.
Im pretty beginner as you could see.

So Im trying to have a single character drawn on a console and I want its position to be updated.
Now please note that I know my code is probably very bad in multiple ways and that there are probably hundreds better completely alternative ways to do this, but I want to understand some inheritance concepts first and why it doesn't work the way it is.

So, I draw my player character "X" on the console, then I update its position calling a specific member method to move it.
Now, because I made it that Player class expand DrawConsole class, I would like to call drawConsole on the Player instance.

When I do this, I have that playerA instance have its position coordinates actually updated, but the reference to the player instance have now two member called 'position', as you can see on the image.
How can I say to choice the playerA one without completely remake the code or use a completely different approach?
Or maybe simply I cant and I have actually complete change the approach?
Hope I was able to comunicate what my doubt actually is.

Here is the code

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "windows.h"

#define width 100
#define height 15

class StaticBuffer
{
public:
    StaticBuffer() { srand(time(0)); }

    void loadBackGround(CHAR_INFO *backGround, int swidth, int sheight)
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < sheight; y++)
        {
            int rnd = rand() % 100 + 1;
            for (int x = 0; x < swidth; x++)

                if (y == 0 || y == sheight - 1)
                {
                    backGround[y * swidth + x].Char.AsciiChar = (unsigned char)127;
                    backGround[y * swidth + x].Attributes = (unsigned char)23;
                }
                else if (x > 4 * rnd && x < (4 * rnd) + 5 || x > 4 * rnd / 2 && x < (4 * rnd / 2) + 5)
                {
                    backGround[y * swidth + x].Char.AsciiChar = (unsigned char)178;
                    backGround[y * swidth + x].Attributes = (unsigned char)12;
                }
                else
                {
                    backGround[y * swidth + x].Char.AsciiChar = 32;
                    backGround[y * swidth + x].Attributes = (unsigned char)3;
                }
        }

    }

private:
};

class DrawConsole
{
public:
    DrawConsole()
    {
        wConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        rConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        windowSizeInit = {0, 0, 30, 10};
        windowSize = {0, 0, bufferSize.X - 1, bufferSize.Y - 1};
        backGround = new CHAR_INFO[bufferSize.X * bufferSize.Y];
        obstacle = new CHAR_INFO[bufferSize.X * bufferSize.Y];
        inputBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[4];
        drawBackGround.loadBackGround(backGround, bufferSize.X, bufferSize.Y);
        nInputWritten = 0;
        nOutputWritten = 0;
        playerString[0] = L'X';
        charLenght = 1;
        position = {10,13};
    }

    void drawConsole()
    {
        wConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        rConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

        SetConsoleWindowInfo(wConsole, TRUE, &windowSizeInit);
        wConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wConsole, bufferSize);
        SetConsoleWindowInfo(wConsole, TRUE, &windowSize);

        WriteConsoleOutputA(wConsole, backGround, bufferSize, {0,0}, &windowSize);
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(wConsole, playerString, charLenght, position, &nOutputWritten);
    }

    void drawChar()
    {
        WriteConsoleOutputA(wConsole, backGround, bufferSize, {0,0}, &windowSize);
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(wConsole, playerString, charLenght, position, &nOutputWritten);
    }


protected:
    HANDLE wConsole;
    HANDLE rConsole;

    COORD bufferSize{width, height};
    SMALL_RECT windowSizeInit;
    SMALL_RECT windowSize;

    CHAR_INFO *backGround;
    CHAR_INFO *obstacle;

    INPUT_RECORD *inputBuffer;
    DWORD nInputWritten;
    DWORD nOutputWritten;
    DWORD charLenght;

    StaticBuffer drawBackGround;
    wchar_t playerString[2];


    COORD position;
};

class Player :public DrawConsole
{
public:
    Player()
    {
        position.X = 20;
        position.Y = height - 2;
    }

    void movePlayerRight()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            position.X += 1;
    }
    COORD getPositionC() { return position; }

private:

    COORD position;
};
Player *playerA = new Player;
DrawConsole *myConsole = new DrawConsole;

int main()
{
    myConsole->drawConsole();
    while (true)
    {
        //Sleep(5000);
        playerA->movePlayerRight();
        playerA->drawChar();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just remove the position member from the derived class.

Comment: I need it to call movePlayerRight() on a Player instance.

Comment: "I need it" You need either one position or two different position. If you need one position, you need one variable named "position". Remove the other one. If you need two different positions, you need two variables, but it would be a really bad idea to name them both "position". Rename the other one. If you can't decide whether you want one position or two different positions, you have a design problem, not a C++ problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you really want. If the idea is that both variables represent the same concept, you shouldn't have to re-define it in the derived class, because it is "protected" in the base class so the derived class is able to access it.

If the variables represent different things, but they happen to have the same name (which, by the way, would be a bad idea), you can qualify it with the class the variable has been defined in. So, for instance, you could do:

```
DrawConsole::position.X += 1;
```

To modify the `position` variable declared in `DrawConsole` and:

```
Player::position.X += 1;
```

To modify the `position` variable declared in `Player`

But, as I said before, I would try to avoid having two variables with the same name because it can easily result in errors.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to maintain the inheritance as is, just remove the attribute `position` from `Player`. The reason is as follows:

Currently, when you call `drawChar`, you are executing code that is in the `DrawConsole` class (`Player` itself does not define a `drawChar` method). This code cannot access `Player::position` because a method in a parent class cannot access an attribute in a child class (even if you are calling the method from an instance of the child class), so it only sees `DrawConsole::position` and that is the variable that it is using.

But when you call `movePlayerRigth` in an instance of `Player`, the code that is being executed is a method in the `Player` class. This method tries to access a position attribute and it finds out that there are two possibilities: `DrawConsole::position` and `Player::position`. In this case, it chooses `Player::position` because it is defined in the same class.

So, you have a method that draws the console based on `DrawConsole::position` and another method that modifies `Player::position`. This can't work and in fact if you run it, you will see that the X is not moving.

If you remove the `position` variable from `Player`, in `movePlayerRight` when you try to access the variable `position`, the code will see that `Player` does not define a position attribute, but it realizes that its parent class (`DrawConsole`) does indeed define a `position` attribute, and with protected access. Being protected means that code in child classes can access it directly, and so `movePlayerRight` will modify `DrawConsole::position`. In this case, both `drawChar` and `movePlayerRight` will access the same variable and it will work as expected.

So, if you want it this way, remove from the Player class the line:

```
COORD position;
```

And you will see that the code compiles and works as expected (the X moves right) because now the code in `Player` and the code in `DrawConsole` are accessing both the same variable (`DrawConsole::position`).

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. I just want to update the coordinate position on my playerA instance and then call drawChar to make it appear on the screen in another position. They represent the same thing but the problem is that I have to have both "position" variables in this concept. In the playerA instance I need it because I want it to represent the current player position to update. In drawChar I have to have it cause WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW need it in its body. So the problem.

Comment: Well, my answer tried to address the idea of accessing two variables with the same name in the innheritance, but the main problem is that you have a Player class that inherits from a "DrawConsole" class, which in fact represents a console (you even name it "myConsole"). But a player is not a console, a console contains a player, so Player should be an attribute of DrawConsole, not a child. Anyway, if this is just for a test, remove the position attribute from Player and you will see that the code still compiles correctly because it will then access the position attribute in DrawConsole.

Comment: My goal was to have a class that "draw" things on the screen and another that represent what I want to draw on the screen. I could have made the thing passing parameters for example, but I wanted to experience some inheritance, that is the point. So my goal was to have a class that draw, but using data from another class that I manipulate somehow somewhere else. So, in this way, it seemed not the wrong way to me to have Player be a child of Draw. Let say I want to do this without passing parameters around. What I should do? Is it even possible? Anyway, thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you want to maintain the inheritance, then the solution is removing position from Player. I have updated the answer to explain the reason behind this.

Comment: Larranaga Just wow. The exact thing I wanted to realize and the right words to make a beginner understand each single word. Thank you very much mate for the time you spent on this.

Comment: So inheritance mean I can use method AND MANIPULATE DATA on my parent, down from an instance of a child so to speak...ok I get it. I had it in my mind somehow being not able to manage it properly though. Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: Yes, from the child you can access and manipulate data on the parent. But remember that only if the data is marked `public` (because then everybody can access it) or `protected` (because you are a child class). If it is marked `private` it's not accessible.